# Play 2.4.2 Scala controllers.Assets.at action not found

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.4

I'm using Play 2.4.2 with Scala.

This is my routes file.

```
GET /favicon.ico            controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file="images/favicon.png")
GET /robots.txt             controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file="files/robots.txt")
GET /                       controllers.Default.redirect(to = "http://www.marketingpage.local")
GET /assets/*file           controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)

GET /:id                    controllers.XController.method0(id: String)
GET /path/:id               controllers.XController.method1(id: String)
```

I'm using the injected routes generator.  This is in my build.

routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator,

The /, /:id, /path/:id routes work fine in development and production however none of the assets are returned in production on those pages.

Further testing revealed none of the routes using controllers.Assets.at work in production.  They do work on my local machine during development.

In production, if I try to access an asset directly I get the default "Action not found for request 'GET /assets/stylesheets/attachments.css'" for example.

So the requests for the assets are reaching the Play server.

I've tried everything I can find to resolve this issue.

I suspect this has something to do with the dependency injection.

Any ideas?

Comment: How you build production? If you use `stage/dist` build try looking for `your_project_name-your_version-assets.jar` in `lib` folder. If this jar contains your assets, then turn on debug, run play as `testProd`, go to `play.api.controllers.AssetsBuilder` class, and debug `assetAt` method. You have provided little information to give an accurate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Some hints to diagnose this issue :

1. Be sure you use the recommended way to build your application : [Play2.4 doc - Building with dist](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Production#Using-the-dist-task)
2. Check that in your `target` directory, sbt packaged well all your assets in a dedicated jar :

> When you package your application, all assets for the application, including all sub projects, are aggregated into a single jar, in target/my-first-app-1.0.0-assets.jar. This jar is included in the distribution so that your Play application can serve them. This jar can also be used to deploy the assets to a CDN or reverse proxy

3. Be sure you didn't miss-configured your `build.sbt`, especially the `pipelineStages`  (try a fresh project to compare - `activator new`)
4. Be sure you didn't edit `/project` files (try a fresh project to compare)
5. Double check your configuration in `application.conf` for `assets.XXX` values (remove these configurations to try)
6. Be sure your front-end server does not trap your `/public` requests

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a conflict between SBT plugins.  I wrote a custom plugin for older versions of Play that didn't support sbt-native-packager that, essentially, did the same thing that the 2.4 build system now does using sbt-native-packager.  The conflict was preventing dist from building and packaging the web-assets jar.  So I'm removing my plugin and migrating the settings to the equivalent support built in to the Play build tools.